# How to get cell value of a GridView from selectedvalue of a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I have a populated GridView and and a DropDownList.

The gridview is consist of header and data for eg. like below:
Package Type, Dimension is the headers, rows consists of
Carton then 1,
and the next row is Bag then 0.

Package Type |  Dimension
Carton       |     1
Bag          |     0

The dropdownlist list of items are Carton, Bag.
When user select Carton, I want to retrieve the data 1 under the Dimension column.

How to programmatically do in SelectedIndexChanged event of the dropdownlist?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPackageType" PageSize="20" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Record Found" Width="100%" EnableViewState="true"
    DataKeyNames="PackageTypeCode" CssClass="DispHid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PackageType" HeaderText="Package Type Name" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsPackageTypeDimension" HeaderText="Dimension" HtmlEncode="False" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackageType" Width="120px" Height="23px" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPackageType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void ddlPackageType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //what to do here
}
```

Comment: Could you please show what you tried already?

Comment: Done paste some codes snippets.

Comment: You filter the source data of the GridView in `ddlPackageType_SelectedIndexChanged` and rebind the Grid.